# Error accessing Search API using C# in SharePoint 2013: Your search cannot be completed because no Search service is available

Tags: c#, search, sharepoint-2013

I am using the server-side object model to try and call the search service (for querying against the search index). The code looks like this:

```
using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(http://ValidSharePointSite))
                {
                    KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(siteCollection);
                    keywordQuery.QueryText = "search text";
                    SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
                    ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
                    resultTableCollection.Filter("Pages", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
                    ResultTable resultTable = resultTableCollection.FirstOrDefault();
                    DataTable dataTable = resultTable.Table;
            }
```

When it hits the line where the KeywordQuery object is created, the following error is thrown: Your search cannot be completed because no Search service is available

I've tried the code on two different SharePoint servers/envs and the same issue happens.  There is some additional info in the logs about not being able to find the HostController Service. Any suggestions?

Comment: I also tried the FullTextSqlQuery class. No luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution:
http://coder87.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/keywordquery-doesnt-work-or-confusion-between-search-namespaces/#comment-484

Must use **Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query** instead of **Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.Query**;

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your search service is up and no errors specified. Also through Search REST API in browser you can able to validate if search is working correctly

Comment: Search works fine (incremental and full crawls). I can also hit the search service via OData URL in the browser. All that is working fine. Just having issues on the server side using the code mentioned above.